# An inequality of n-dimensional measure

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, optimization, lebesgue-measure

### Background

**the measure of $n$-dimensional simplex**

A simplex is a generalization of the notion of a triangle or tetrahedron to arbitrary dimensions.More formally, suppose the$ n + 1$ points ${ a_{0},\dots ,a_{n}\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}} $are affinely independent, which means ${ a_{1}-a_{0},\dots ,a_{n}-a_{0}} $are linearly independent. Then, the simplex determined by them is the set of points:$A_n=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^ns_ka_k\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^ns_k=1,s_k\geq0\right\}$and the $n$-dimensional measure of it is that $M\left(A_n\right)=\dfrac{1}{n!}\left|det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}-a_{10}&a_{12}-a_{10}&\dots&a_{1n}-a_{10}\\a_{21}-a_{20}&a_{22}-a_{20}&\dots&a_{2n}-a_{20}\\ \dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\\a_{n1}-a_{n0}&a_{n2}-a_{n0}&\dots&a_{nn}-a_{n0}\end{pmatrix}\right|$($a_{ij}$ represents the $i$th component of vector $a_j$)

**the measure of $n$-dimensional hypersphere**

I want to generalize the measure of $n$-dimensional hypersphere. At first, I defined the n-dimensional hypersphere as:$B_n^t\left(r\right)=\left\{\left(x_1,x_2,...,x_n\right)\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\left|x_k\right|^t\leq r^t\right\}$Through the recurrence relation satisfied by the $n$-dimensional measure of$B_n^t\left(r\right)$--$M_1^t\left(r\right)=2r$,$M_{n+1}^t\left(r\right)=2\int_0^r M_{n+1}^t\left[\left(r^t-x^t\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}\right]$,we can easily figure out $M_n^t\left(r\right)=\dfrac{\left[2r\Gamma\left(\dfrac{t+1}{t}\right)\right]^n}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{t+n}{t}\right)}$.
And then I generalized the definition of n-dimensional hypersphere as:$B_n^t\left(r\right)=\left\{\left(x_1,x_2,...,x_n\right)\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\dfrac{x_k}{r_k}\right|^{t_k}\leq 1\right\}$.The former is the special case of this when $r_k=r$ and $t_k=t$.Similarly, it's not hard to figure out $M_n^t\left(r\right)=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n 2r_k\Gamma\left(1+t_k^{-1}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^nt_k^{-1}\right)}$.

### Question

1. Now,I want to generalize once again the definition of an n-dimensional hypersphere as:$B_n=\left\{\left(x_1,x_2,...,x_n\right)\bigg|\left|\sum_{k=1}^ne^{i\theta_k}\left|\dfrac{x_k}{r_k}\right|^{t_k}\right|\leq 1\right\}$.The former is the special case of this when $\theta_k=\theta$ .So what the the $n$-dimensional measure of it?
2. For an $n$-dimensional simplex $A$ and $n$-dimensional hypersphere $B$(Using the latest definition mentioned in the first question,Given sequence $\left\{t_n\right\}$ and $\left\{\theta_n\right\}$), if the following inequality always holds:$M\left(A\cap B\right)\leq \lambda
    M\left(A\right)+\mu M\left(A\right)$,find the minimum value of $\lambda+\mu$.